# Multiple jQuery in the same place

Tags: jquery

I'm using multiple jQuery in the same page.

1. menu
2. picture slider
3. picture carousel
4. fancybox

when used individually they work perfectly. However, when combined in the same page they work on safari, firefox, chrome, opera, etc except for IE.

I've tried the noconflict() script and it did not work. (I think might be doing it wrong) Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

here is the code:

```
<!--JS STARTS-->

  <!--MAIN NAV .JS-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddsmoothmenu.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu-settings.js"> </script>
  <!--MAIN NAV .JS ENDS-->

  <!--QUICK RESERVATION CALENDAR TOGGLE-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/toggle.js"></script>
  <!--QUICK RESERVATION CALENDAR TOGGLE .JS ENDS-->

  <!--FANCYBOX-->
  <script type="text/javascript"
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
  <!--FANCYBOX .JS ENDS-->

  <!--FOOTER SLIDESHOW-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tinycarousel.min.js"></script>
  <!--FOOTER SLIDESHOW .JS ENDS-->

  <!--PROMO PICTURE SLIDESHOW-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
  <!--PROMO PICTURE SLIDESHOW .JS ENDS-->

  <!--DOCUMENT READY-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slideshow').cycle({fx:'fade', speed:'100000', timeout: 10000, next:'#next', prev:'#prev'});
      $('#slider1').tinycarousel({ display: 7 });
      $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
    });
  </script>
  <!--DOCUMENT READY ENDS-->
```

Comment: what is the `js/jquery2.js` script?

Comment: THANKKKKKKSSSSSSS!!!!! i've been trying to figure this out for  like 2 days. I think it came with this script. I just took it off and it looks like it's working.... Thanks again a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is interfering:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery2.js"></script>
```

It's loading another OLD (1.1.2) copy of jQuery. Remove this and it should work correctly.

Comment: my pleasure :) It was a funny one as the error message you get in the IE developer tools isn't directly linked to this, so a bit of logical thinking (and variable watches) worked :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You actually don't need to reference the same library of the same version each time you employ a new plugin. Do it once.
2. NoConflict is used when you might overload the $ operator with another library (like mootools)
3. Please post a link to a page so we can maybe advise on what exactly does not work.

Comment: Thanks arthur. I took off where the same library was duplicated but it still does not work. Here is the link http://dffernandez.com/client_review_files/naples